# One instance of a class changing property value but other instance doesn't get updated with the change of property in swift

Tags: swift

Here as you can see class SameData there are two instances data1 and data2. If I change data2 instances userName that is stored in the class properties it doesn't get updated in data1 instance of the same class.

In swift class should get updated in all instances when properties change in one instance. But why this is happening?

Code:

```
class SameData { 
var userName = "Anonymous" 
} 
var data1 = SameData()
var data2 = SameData() 
data2.userName = "Not Anonymous"
print(data2.userName) 
print(data1.userName)
```

Result:

```
"Not Anonymous\n"
"Anonymous\n"
```

As this is a class and one instance is changing userName then all the instances of the class should adopt the change am I right? So, the result should be something like this.

Expected Result:

```
"Not Anonymous\n"
"Not Anonymous\n"
```

Comment: "As this is a class and one instance is changing userName then all the instances of the class should adopt the change" - absolutely wrong. Where did you get such idea? Are you confusing with `class` or `static` property?

Comment: I just saw a youtube video where the video explains something like this. That a class in swift changed its property entirely in all instances even when only one instance changes the value of the property all the instances get updated. 

If it's not true so can you explain me this: https://im.ge/i/FKRJk6

@sfgblackwarkrts

Comment: You get the desired result by replacing `var data2 = SameData()` with `var data2 = data1` which copies the **pointer** to the instance. Each call of `SameData()` creates a new, **different** instance/pointer.

Comment: @RakibHasan You're mixing up references and instances. Suppose you have a phone, and you know its phone number. When you want me to call you, you give me your phone number (not the phone itself). When you change your voice mail message, you can call your phone number and observe the that change. But because my copy of your phone number points to your same phone, I can also observe the change to your voice mail message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain as an answer, since I can't fit it into comment.

- In `var data1 = SameData()` the `SameData()` is the object, and `data1` is like a finger pointing to that object.
- Then when you say `var data2 = SameData()`: you create a second object, and point a finger `data2` to that object.

**So you have 2 objects, and 2 fingers pointing to each object respectively, neither object knows about existence of the other.**

Now, if you do `var data2 = data1`, you are *not* creating a new object, instead you are pointing *another finger* `data2` to the *same* object you previously created. So here you have 2 fingers pointing to the same object.

Hence in first case, by changing `data1` you are changing the first object, but the second object (to which `data2` points) remains intact.

In second case, by changing `data1`, you are changing the only object you have. And since both fingers point to that same object, they both see the change.

Lets look at the case of structures:

```
struct SomeData {
    var userName = "Anonymous" 
}
```

Structures, just like arrays and dictionaries are *value types* in swift, which means they have no finger pointing to the object (and there's no object), just the structure itself. So unlike the classes, the structures are **copied** on assignment. I.e. in

```
var data1 = SameData()
var data2 = data1
```

we create a structure `data1`, then we copy it to `data2`. As the result we have 2 identical instances of the structure. If we were to change one of the structures, the other structure won't change. E.g.

```
data2.userName = "Not Anonymous"
```

means we changed `data2` and not `data1`

By the way, [here's an excellent article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) from Apple on this topic:

Comment: For struct in swift if I have two fingers like in the second case and pointing to one object but the result is not the same.

Results :
"Not Anonymous\n"
"Anonymous\n"

When using struct in the second case. Here is the code if you need to see: https://ibb.co/c8McpXh

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in the case of using a struct and what's the difference between class and struct in this case?

Comment: @realrakibhasan added explanation about structures.

Answer (score 1):

> in the class properties

These aren't class properties. These are just instance properties, on two different instances. Naturally, changing one doesn't change the other. That's the whole point of instances. *They're separate instances.* These are just instance properties [with default values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID204), similar to writing:

```
class SameData { 
    var userName: String

    init() {
        self.userName = "Anonymous" 
    }
}
```

Class properties are marked with `class` (or similarly, `static`, which is roughly equivalent to `class final`).

That said, marking a username as a class constant doesn't really make sense. Presumably, each user should have their own username, and they should be independent. You should add more detail on the kind of data you're trying to model, so we can give more concrete advice on thow to handle it.